# Defining Default Excerpt in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

The support team for the company which provided my WordPress theme claims that the developers have not provided support for excerpts.

This is strange since the blog template contains the following:

```
<!-- CPT Excerpt -->
<div class="cpt-excerpt">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

The current behaviour is that if I provide no manual excerpt in the post editor, the full post gets displayed on the blog listing page. I can provide an excerpt manually, but this is inefficient.

I've tried adding

```
/**
 * Excerpt Length
 **/
function mytheme_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'mytheme_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

to `functions.php` but no success.

Could someone please explain how to have `the_excerpt()` display a default length excerpt of, say, 100 characters, with all tags stripped so headings etc. appear as plain text in the excerpt?

I'm surprised that `the_excerpt()` doesn't do this by default, but maybe there's something about the theme that has got in the way...?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If you have doubts on your theme doing stuff, just try to switch to another theme temporarely and see what happen. About your issue you could try do do this: wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt());